# Plasma-nm in NixOS

Tags: applet, kde-plasma, nixos

I'm having some trouble finding plasma-nm in nixpkgs. I can see [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/nix-commits@lists.science.uu.nl/msg11159.html) that the package exists, and is even registered in `all-packages.nix`... so why doesn't `nix-env -qa` list it as a derivation? I'm sorry if there is an obvious answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are using an old nixpkgs version, e.g. 14.04 instead of unstable.

Comment: I don't think I am, I've got a cloned repo straight from https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. `sudo nix-env -I {,nixpkgs=}/opt/nixpkgs/ -qa |grep plasma` only returns the kdeplasma-addons :/.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I see where I messed up - the `-f` option is what I was supposed to use. Thank you for your help!!

`nix-env -qaf /opt/nixpkgs/ |grep plasma` got it :)